# How can I write/append a column in a dbf file in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.8, dbf

I'm having trouble appending a dbf file column in python 3.8.

The first step in which I read the values from `SERIAL_NUM` column is working; however in some cases I need to append to the `SERIAL_NUM` column and I get this error:

`"AttributeError: 'DBF' object has no attribute 'append'"`

I am struggling to understand what is causing this issue - please help me understand how to append/write a dbf column in python.

```
import dbf
from dbfread import DBF

table = DBF('C://Users//e833519//Desktop//VALIDATE.dbf', load=True)

table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)

for i in range(len(table)):

            if((len(self.entry.get())<11) or (len(self.entry.get())>12) ):

                self.result="snIncorect"

                break

            elif(table.records[i]['SERIAL_NUM']==self.entry.get()):

                self.result="Compass"

                break

            else:

                self.result="notCompass" 

if ((self.result=="notCompass") and (self.verificareSiIntroducereCompass.get()==True)):

            table.append("something on the column X")
```

Comment: As the module name suggests, `dbfread` is for *reading* `.dbf` files. It's intended for one-off, one-way conversions, as the documentation clearly explains.

Comment: @BoarGules
so what it's the correct module to be used?

Comment: The `.dbf` format went obsolete a generation ago. *The correct module* might not exist. There were two Python 2 modules that offered some write functionality. (1) Module `dbf` (https://pythonhosted.org/dbf/)—support ceased 2012. (2) Module `dbfpy` (https://pypi.org/project/dbfpy/)—support ceased 2015. Writing to a `.dbf` is a good deal harder than reading one, because it has to maintain the index files. dBase indexes can be based on an arbitrary dBase expression, so write support requires reimplementing a substantial subset of the dBase language. That is a lot to expect.

Comment: @BoarGules:  `dbf` is still alive and well (at least, as well as it ever was, and I definitely still support it) .

Comment: @BoarGules: I also released the latest version in March of this year, so why do you think support ended in 2012?

Comment: @EthanFurman If you follow the link in my comment you will see source code that shows support of Python up to 2.7, and documentation from 2012. That came higher in the Google ranking of my search than anything you published subsequently. Now that you point it out, and I know to look further, I see https://pypi.org/project/dbf/ is very recent. My apologies.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem.  I loaded that documentation as an experiment, and haven't figured out how to take it down since.  :-/

Comment: @BoarGules: Okay, just deleted that documentation.  Now I need to figure out where to put the current docs.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem you have is that you are using two different dbf packages at the same time.  That what you have is working at all is pure luck.

As BoarGules mentioned, `dbfread` is for reading, and you are using `dbfread.DBF` to open the file, so you have no write support.

Finally, when you say "append" do you mean "fill in a value in column X"?  In that case column X should already exist, and you are not appending, but writing to that column.

You need to use `dbf` by itself:

```
import dbf

table = dbf.Table('C:/Users/e833519/Desktop/VALIDATE.dbf')

table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)

for rec in table:

    entry = self.entry.get()

    if len(entry) < 11 or len(entry) > 12:

        self.result = "snIncorect"

    elif rec['SERIAL_NUM'] == entry:

        self.result = "Compass"

    else:

        self.result = "notCompass" 

if self.result == "notCompass" and self.verificareSiIntroducereCompass.get():

    dbf.write(rec, {'column_X': "something"})
```

The above code is also slightly rewritten to be in the style of Python.